# Version 0.5.0.1-Beta

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery

I forgot about my bitcoin account until recently.  I have the software version listed above and my last real transaction was in 2012.  I don't remember my password, but my 12 year old PC does.  Do I need to transfer this to a wallet?  I have done a test transfer with $100 or so but it hasn't kicked off.  I noticed the S/W is "Catching up" and "Downloaded 173968 blocks of transaction history".  And "Last received block was generated 2121 days ago".  Any advice?  Do I need to wait for it to "Catch up"?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations! Safely exit the software, create a safe backup copy (check that everything is copied correctly) and upgrade to the newest official version for your operating system. You will need >400GB of free storage in total for the full blockchain once it finishes catching up, including what you have already, or you can set the `-prune=` mode on.